# Salesforce Sales Wave Default Dataset load - how to refresh metadata?

Tags: einstein-analytics

Just starting with Sales Wave, on the first load using the Wizard I had an error where a custom field existed on Opportunity and Opportunity Product with the same label and API name. I've amended the Opportunity Product field label and API name, but still get the error.

How can I force a refresh metadata / or how can I get to the field name loaded to update it manually in wave to try again?